# Answer Not Saved as Draft After Stuck on Human Check

Tags: support, bug

I took a long time to type up a very thorough answer, hit the post/submit button, and left for dinner. I came back to my computer several hours later and found that my post attempt was stuck on Human Check. I didn't have the presence of mind to try the back button (just in case it would have worked) but I completed the Human Check and then I got sent back to the list of questions. I did go back to that question just to check but my answer wasn't saved as a draft and neither was it posted.

So why wasn't my answer at least saved as a draft?

Comment: Do you have a browser?

Comment: Back button usually loads from browser cache, so it would have recovered it. Though on doing the Human Check, the answer should get submitted.

Comment: @random I was using chrome.